# Azure Data Factory CI/CD - automatic publish after merge to master branch

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory

we are building CI/CD solution over our Azure Data Factory, and what I'm missing and what I was not able to get answer for after some searching is if there is possibility to automate publishing from collaboration branch to our **adf_publish** branch. So desired workflow should be:

1. Create feature branch
2. When you are satisfied with changes create pull request
3. Pull request is approved and merged to collaboration(master) branch
4. After merge, pipeline **will automatically publish changes to development Azure Data Factory service** and reflect the changes in **adf_publish** branch. Without someone **pushing Publish button** in UI.
5. If necessary release pipelines are triggered from adf_publish branch to other environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is currently unavailable in adf, kindly vote for the adf feedback link below:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/40556329-please-allow-users-to-automate-publish

Comment: thanks, I will mark this as an answer, because trully this is kind of pain, BUT there is third party solution, which simulates desired behaviour. If you are interested just check out videos and tool Mr. Nowinski has created here https://sqlplayer.net/adftools/

Answer (score 0):

This has been added to Azure Data Factory and Azure DevOps Pipelines as of early 2021.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements#the-new-cicd-flow